# How to simulate incoming calls on a real device?

Tags: android, simulation, phone-call

For testing purposes I want to simulate/spoof incomming calls on a real android device (ie. not the emulator). I know that [DDMS provides this feature for emulators](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#ops-location), but I am unable to find a solution for actual devices connected by usb.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is translated from another language, but this doesn't really make sense in English. Maybe try to explain it a different way.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I want to simulate incoming calls on a real device.

Comment: I'm not sure the purpose of "simulating" a call when you can just call the phone and hang up...  But, if your trying to force a different activity over your own, you can set the alarm on the phone, then open you app and wait for the alarm to go off.

Comment: @Chris you can use it for auto. test, also not everybody has multiple sims/devices readily laying around and last it is easier to just click on a button or send a cmd then to call and wait with a real device

Comment: It is pretty clear what is being asked here. This site is sometimes depressing.

Answer (score -5):

In the [Using DDMS documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html), check out the section titled **Spoofing calls or SMS text messages**.

DDMS is an executable that lives in your `tools` directory in the Android SDK.

Comment: no simulate in emulate, simulate in device, as faker call.

Comment: DDMS only seems to support fake incomming calls in an emulator not for a "real" device

Comment: deserve a -1 . Cuz the question is about real device not emulator.